# GROUP BY tsql, multiple records to return one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

I have a table as follows:

```
INSTR_ID    PRC_TMS     PRC_CURR_CDE    PRC_TYP    PRC_QUOTE_AMT
5901        31/03/2015  EUR             CLO         89.73
5901        31/03/2015  EUR             LST         89.53
1123        31/03/2015  USD             CLO         12.35
```

What I need to be able to do is query a select on this, but where I've got multiple INSTR_ID's, if I have a CLO PRC_TYP then return that PRC_QUOTE_AMT, else the LST PRC_QUOTE_AMT.

I've looked at group by, but unsure of how to build the logic to select CLO else LST?

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should edit your query and show the results you want to get.

Comment: I'm not understanding what it is you want.  Do you want to have one row for each unique `INSTR_ID` and sum the amounts in `PRC_QUOTE_AMT`? if the `PRC_TYP` is "CLO"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prioritize the rows (choosing one) by using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by INSTR_ID
                                order by (case when PRC_TYP = 'CLO' then 1
                                               when PRC_TYPE = 'LST' then 2
                                               else 3
                                          end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

For the data you provide, you can also use `group by`:

```
select INSTR_ID, PRC_TMS, PRC_CURR_CDE,
       coalesce(max(case when PRC_TYP = 'CLO' then PRC_QUOTE_AMT end),
                max(PRC_QUOTE_AMT) ) as PRC_QUOTE_AMT
from table t
group by INSTR_ID, PRC_TMS, PRC_CURR_CDE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Return if CLO, also return if no row with same id and CLO exists.

```
select * from tablename t1
where PRC_TYP = 'CLO'
 or not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                where t1.INSTR_ID = t2.INSTR_ID
                 and t2.PRC_TYP = 'CLO')
```